# Discrepancy when calculating $\int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{\ln(2x-1)}{x^2} dx$ using two methods.

Tags: calculus, integration, proof-verification, definite-integrals

So I am trying to calculate this integral: $$\int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{\ln(2x-1)}{x^2} dx$$

I do not understand why method 2 gives the wrong result.

**Method 1**

$$\int \frac{\ln(2x-1)}{x^2} dx = -\frac{1}{x} \times \ln(2x - 1) + 2\int \frac{1}{x} \times \frac{1}{2x - 1} dx$$

Using partial decomposition we can write $\int \frac{1}{x} \times \frac{1}{2x - 1} dx$ as $\frac{1}{x(2x-1)} = \frac{A}{2x - 1} + \frac{B}{x} = Ax + 2Bx - B$ which gives us $A = 2, B = -1$.

We can then write the original expressions as:

$$\int \frac{\ln(2x-1)}{x^2} dx = -\frac{1}{x} \times \ln(2x - 1) + 2\int \frac{2}{2x - 1} - \frac{1}{x} dx$$

$$ = -\frac{1}{x} \times \ln(2x - 1) + 2\ln(2x - 1) - 2\ln(x) + C$$

This can be written as:

$$ =2\ln(\frac{2x - 1}{x}) -\frac{\ln(2x - 1)}{x}  + C$$

As $x \rightarrow \infty, 2\ln(\frac{2x - 1}{x}) \rightarrow 2\ln(2)$, and $-\frac{\ln(2x - 1)}{x} \rightarrow 0$

*The results is $2\ln(2)$ which is correct.*

**Method 2**

$$\int \frac{\ln(2x-1)}{x^2} dx = -\frac{1}{x} \times \ln(2x - 1) + 2\int \frac{1}{x} \times \frac{1}{2x - 1} dx$$

Starting of with a simple substiution in the right hand integral

$$z = 2x - 1, x = \frac{z+1}{2}, dx = \frac{1}{2}dz$$

We get:

$$-\frac{1}{x} \times \ln(2x - 1) + 2\int \frac{2}{z+1} \times \frac{1}{z} \times \frac{1}{2}dz$$

Simplified to:

$$ -\frac{1}{x} \times \ln(2x - 1) + \int \frac{2}{z+1} \times \frac{1}{z}dz$$

Using partial decomposition we can write $\int \frac{2}{z+1} \times \frac{1}{z}dz$ as $\frac{2}{(z+1)z} = \frac{A}{z+1} + \frac{B}{z} = Az + Bz + B$ which gives us $A = -2, B = 2$.

We can then write the original expressions as:

$$\int \frac{\ln(2x-1)}{x^2} dx = -\frac{1}{x} \times \ln(2x - 1) + 2\int \frac{2}{z} - \frac{2}{z+1} dx$$

$$ = -\frac{1}{x} \times \ln(2x - 1) + 2\ln(z) - 2\ln(z+1) + C$$

Plugging back $z=2x-1$ we get:

$$ = -\frac{1}{x} \times \ln(2x - 1) + 2\ln(2x-1) - 2\ln(2x) + C$$

This can be written as:

$$ =2\ln(\frac{2x - 1}{2x}) -\frac{\ln(2x - 1)}{x} + C$$

As $x \rightarrow \infty, 2\ln(\frac{2x - 1}{2x}) \rightarrow 0$, and $-\frac{\ln(2x - 1)}{x} \rightarrow 0$

*The results is $0$ which is incorrect.*

I cannot see why this is so...

Comment: the right result is $$-2\,\ln  \left( 2\,x \right) +{\frac {\ln  \left( 2\,x-1 \right) 
 \left( 2\,x-1 \right) }{x}}
$$

Comment: Note that $\frac{2}{(z+1)z}=\frac{-2}{z+1}+\frac{2}{z}$, i.e., the constant $2$ which you took out of the integral later is in fact already included.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are forgetting that it's a definite integral and you have to compute both upper and lower limits,

In the second method the integral is 0 as $x \rightarrow \infty$, but it is $-2\ln(2)$ at $1$. So, the answer is $2\ln(2)$

Comment: Of course! Thank you! Since in "method 1" the lower limit was $0$, i forgot about it using "method 2".